# Css transition property not work when add and remove class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

when we add and remove class using jquery transition works but when I try to do the same work with the JavaScript it was not working.

Please help me to figure out why this is happen?

Here is the my HTML Code.

```
<button id="contact" onclick="showContactUs()">Contact us Form</button>

<div id="contact-us">
    <p id="hide" onclick="hideContactUs()">fdfg</p>
</div>
```

my script.js

```
const buttonName = document.getElementById( 'contact-us' );
      
showContactUs = () => {
    buttonName.classList.remove( 'contact-us-hidden' );
}

hideContactUs = () => {
    buttonName.classList.add( 'contact-us-hidden' );
}
```

my css code

```
#contact-us{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(55, 151, 119);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.contact-us-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The display property cannot be transitioned. Can you add a code snippet showing how you had this working in JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what animation you were using, but you can do something like this:

```js
const buttonName = document.getElementById('contact-us');

function showContactUs() {
  buttonName.classList.remove('contact-us-hidden');
}

function hideContactUs() {
  buttonName.classList.add('contact-us-hidden');
}
```

```css
#contact-us > div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(55, 151, 119);
}

#contact-us,
.contact-us-hidden {
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.contact-us-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* hide from screen with a delay */

#contact-us.contact-us-hidden > div {
  margin-top: -10000px;
  transition: margin-top 0s 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<button id="contact" onclick="showContactUs()">Contact us Form</button>

<div id="contact-us">
  <div>
    <p id="hide" onclick="hideContactUs()">fdfg</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  blah
</div>
```

Note, there is an extra `div` inside `contact-us`, it needed if you want hide it from screen completely, otherwise you can use your original html.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple functions, instead of using arrow functions.

```js
const buttonName = document.getElementById( 'contact-us' );
      
function showContactUs(){
    buttonName.classList.remove( 'contact-us-hidden' );
}

function hideContactUs(){
    buttonName.classList.add( 'contact-us-hidden' );
}
```

```css
#contact-us{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(55, 151, 119);
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.contact-us-hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="contact" onclick="showContactUs()">Contact us Form</button>

<div id="contact-us">
    <p id="hide" onclick="hideContactUs()">fdfg</p>
</div>
```